# how to send attachment using sendgrid mail api

Tags: java, email, attachment, sendgrid

I need to send a mail with attachment in java using **sendgrid api**. I am mentioning files like `[filename.xls]=bytearray`. I am getting this byte array using **jxl api**. I am able to send the mail ,but `xls` is not having the values.

**Code :**

```
sendgridUrl+"?api_user="+apiUser + "&api_key=" + apiPassword + ""
            + to + "&subject=" + (subject.replaceAll(" ", "%20")) + "&fromname="
            + senderPersonal + "&files[" + fileName + "]=" + value2
            + "&html=" + mess‌​age + "&from=" + AppConfig.getProperty("senderemail");
```

Comment: Sharing the code you're using would be extremely helpful for debugging.

Comment: sendgridUrl+"?api_user="+apiUser+"&api_key="+apiPassword+"" +
           to+"&subject="+(subject.replaceAll(" ", "%20"))+"&fromname="+senderPersonal+"&files["+fileName+"]="+value2+"&html="+message+"&from="+AppConfig
     .getProperty("senderemail");

Comment: That doesn't help much because I don't know what any of the variables are.  Please update the actual question with the entire code snippet in question.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static bool SendMailUsingSendgrid(EmailSendRequestDTO request)
        {
            try
            {
                string htmlContent = string.Empty;
                string plainTextContent = string.Empty;

                // Set apikey
                var apiKey = ConfigReader.Read(CommonEnums.ConfigKeys.SendgridApiKey);

                // Initialize sendgrid client.
                var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);

                // From address
                var from = new EmailAddress(request.FromAddress, request.FromDisplayName);

                // Subject
                var subject = request.Subject;

                // Send mail to multiple recepients.
                var recepientList = new List<EmailAddress>();

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.ToAddresses))
                {
                    foreach (var toAddress in request.ToAddresses.Split(new[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                    {
                        recepientList.Add(new EmailAddress(toAddress));
                    }
                }

                // If content in html format
                if (request.IsHtmlFormat)
                {
                    htmlContent = request.Body;
                }
                else
                {
                    plainTextContent = request.Body;
                }

                // Creat object to send mail message.
                var mailMessage = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmailToMultipleRecipients(from, recepientList, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent);

                // add multiple cc.
                var ccList = new List<EmailAddress>();

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.CCAddresses))
                {
                    foreach (var ccAddress in request.CCAddresses.Split(new[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                    {
                        ccList.Add(new EmailAddress(ccAddress));
                    }
                }

                // add multiple bcc.
                var bccList = new List<EmailAddress>();

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.BCCAddresses))
                {
                    foreach (var bccAddress in request.BCCAddresses.Split(new[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                    {
                        bccList.Add(new EmailAddress(bccAddress));
                    }
                }

                // Attachments
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.AttachmentFile))
                {
                    foreach (var attachmentFile in request.AttachmentFile.Split(new[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                    {
                        SendGrid.Helpers.Mail.Attachment messageAttachment = new SendGrid.Helpers.Mail.Attachment();
                        mailMessage.Attachments.Add(messageAttachment);
                    }
                }

                var response = client.SendEmailAsync(mailMessage).Result;

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```